# How to convert recurrent vertical column into rows than stack them together in Python/Pandas?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, transpose, data-manipulation

I am generating some data vertically at first, but would like to transpose them into row data, then stack them into an array like a Pandas data frame. How do I get a final product of a pandas data frame with 4 columns ('fr', 'en', 'ir', 'ab') and three rows?

```
# coding=utf-8
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, Series
import numpy as np
import nltk
import re
import random
from random import randint
import csv
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

# Get csv file into data frame
data = pd.read_csv("FamilySearchData_All_OCT2015_newEthnicity_filledEthnicity_processedName_trimmedCol.csv", header=0, encoding="utf-8")
df = DataFrame(data)

columns = ['fr', 'en', 'ir', 'ab']
classes = ['ethnicity2', 'Ab_group', 'Ab_tribe']
df_count = DataFrame(columns=columns)

for j in classes:
    for i in columns:
        ethnicity_tar = str(i)
        count = 0
        try:
            count = df[str(j)].value_counts()[ethnicity_tar]
        except Exception as e:
            count = ''
        print ethnicity_tar, count
```

Output:

```
fr 1554455
en 1196932
ir 941852
ab 95131
fr 1554444
en 16000
ir 940850
ab 9371
fr 1554600
en 2196931
ir 940957
ab 9399
```

What I would like at the end:

```
fr        en       ir      ab
1554455 1196932 941852  95131
1554444 16000 940850    9371
1554600 2196931 940957  9399
```

Comment: (It would help clarity if the values in your example were unique, e.g. 1554483, 1554484, 1554485)

Comment: The values will be derived from some functions so each row and column will be different. Only used repeating values as demo. I will change them for clarity

Answer (score 0):

To implement this I would create a dictionary (hash) of the column names each containing an array.  Then as I loop through the rows in your file, I'd use the first value to index into the dictionary to get the array and then append the numerical value to that array.

Once this interim data structure is built, you could loop through the arrays pulling the same index value for each row and printing them:

```
for i in range(0, n):
   print str(hash['fr'][i]) + " " +
     str(hash['en'][i]) + " " +
     str(hash['ir'][i]) + " "
     str(hash['ab'][i])
```

Comment: Not sure how or where to add into my code, can you please show your code to fit mine (I am not very advance in python)